# How can I print in one single line after using a for loop

Tags: python, sorting, for-loop

I need your help.
So, I have to separate the words of a string, then I have to sort the letters of the words alphabetically and print them out in one line.

```
words = "apple pumpkin log river fox pond"
words = words.split()

for i in words:
  print("".join(sorted(i)))
```

Comment: You can just do `print(' '.join([''.join(sorted(w)) for w in words]))`

Comment: True, but now its printing "aelpp ikmnppu glo eirrv fox dnop" 6 times

Comment: remove your for loop

Answer (score -2, accepted):

You can use use:

```
words = "apple pumpkin log river fox pond"
words = words.split()

for i in words:
    print("".join(sorted(i)),end= " ")
print("")
```

The "end" string will be printed after the main string. The default value for it is "\n".

Comment: Note that the string printed ends with an empty space: it prints `aelpp ikmnppu glo eirrv fox dnop ` instead of the expected `aelpp ikmnppu glo eirrv fox dnop`.

Comment: You are right about this.

Answer (score 0):

for i in sorted(words):
print("".join(i))

could also do something like initialize an empty string, then add each word with a empty string to space them out

Comment: make sure your code runs

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```py
>>> words = "apple pumpkin log river fox pond"
>>> print(' '.join([''.join(sorted(w)) for w in words.split()]))
aelpp ikmnppu glo eirrv fox dnop
```

Here goes step by step explanation:

```py
>>> words = "apple pumpkin log river fox pond"
>>> words_as_lists = words.split()  # split between words
>>> sorted_words_as_list = [''.join(sorted(w)) for w in words_as_lists]  # sort each word's chars, and let it in a list
>>> result = ' '.join(sorted_words_as_list)  # join sorted words with spaces between them
>>> print(result)
aelpp ikmnppu glo eirrv fox dnop
```